# Example of closed graph but not closed-valued, and $g(x)$ is closed set but g id not closed at $x$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given metric space $(X, d_x)$ and $(Y,d_y)$.
Given correspondence $g:X \rightrightarrows Y$ Could you help me find example of these cases?

1. $g(x)$ is a closed set, but g$ is not closed at $x$.

For this case, I think $g(x) = 1/x$ may work, but I don't know how to prove it.

2. $g$ is closed-valued, but $g$ is not a closed graph.

Comment: what do you mean by "closed at $x$"?

Comment: @FShrike g is closed at x in X if for any sequence (x_k,y_k) with x_k in X and y_k in g(x_k) for all k in N, and (x_k,y_k) converges to (x,y), we have y in g(x)

Comment: For $(1)$ you can take $g$ to be any noncontinuous *function* viewed in its natural way as a correspondence